# Google spreadsheets scripts, passing arrays back and forth

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't seem to perform this simple operation and am wondering if I am simply just missing something obvious. I am trying to send an array back to an HTML file, in the code.gs file it gets created correctly and I can iterate through it as expected but when I pass it back to the html file, it fails.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

contents of my index.html file:

```
<script>
  google.setOnLoadCallback(draw);

  function draw() 
  {
    var rows = google.script.run.callTo();
    alert("this will get called");
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
      alert(rows[i]);
      alert(i);
      alert("this will never get called");
    }
  }
</script>
```

the contents of my Code.gs file:

```
function onOpen()
{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Open this')
    .addItem('Show', 'doGetHtml')
    .addToUi();
}

function callTo()
{
    var empty_array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
    for(i = 0; i < empty_array.length; i++)
    {
        //Browser.msgBox("item2 is " + empty_array[i]);
    }
    return empty_array;
}

function doGetHtml() 
{
    html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setHeight(400)
    .setWidth(1024);

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Show this message');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can only access the value returned from a server-side function by passing it to a success handler: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

```
<script>
  function draw(rows) 
  {
    alert("this will get called");
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
      alert(rows[i]);
      alert(i);
      alert("this will hopefully get called");
    }
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(draw).callTo();
</script>
```